# how to access lines in a pdf page programmatically and give them different colors in python?

Tags: python, pdf

I want to access a pdf page directly and access individual lines.
   I want to change color of every line differently.
   I am using linux and I want to program in python.

Could anyone please let me know the library and the sample code to do so?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283065/programmatically-change-font-color-of-text-in-pdf "It's possible, but not necessarily easy" as Alex Martelli put it.

Comment: It's possible but only for very small values of "possible", depending on the nature of the file you're working with.  Certainly, many files will have no way to figure out where a "line" begins and ends.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the python based library like 
[Reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/)
this is the good library and community support is also well. 
and one another simple library is 
**pythonreport** .

Comment: Thanks, The libraries you specified are for authoring not for parsing. I first want to parse the pdf document and then color every text object differently.