# PDF: Change 1 color on all pages?

Tags: python, pdf, adobe, photoshop, acrobat

So I have this 700 page pdf that's in black, white, and hot pink. The hot pink is both text and non-text (design elements). Is there any way to edit that one color on all the pages at once? I can do it element-by-element on adobe acrobat and page-by-page in photoshop, but those methods just seem impossibly tedious.

I don't know much about coding but can maybe pull together something on python if I'm given great instructions.

Thanks!

Comment: Save it as as anything but PDF and try modifying that IMO. Others have tried... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283065/programmatically-change-font-color-of-text-in-pdf

Comment: Do you have a link to your pdf?  If it's not compressed you may be able to do it with a hex editor.

Comment: Is the "hot pink" a spot color, or is it process color? What about the "white", is it also defined as such? You might look what the Print Production tools of Acrobat Pro can do for you.

Comment: Note: Editing the file with a Hex Editor is not likely to work; you would need to modify the content stream... And the content stream is likely to be compressed, particularly in a 700page document.

Answer (score 0):

Max Wyss has the best suggestion; using Acrobat's Print Production Tools.

Specifically you want to use the 'Convert Colors' Tool.
The key is the 'Conversion Attributes'.
Convert Command: Convert to Profile
Conversion Profile: (Choose from:) Dot Gain ??% or Gray Gamma ?.?
Rendering Intent: for a gray-scale conversion like this, I lean toward 'Perceptual', but it's not a strong preference.

You might want to check the 'preserve black' option.

Test your settings with a small page range before doing the entire document.